I am using EPPlus to write the content in an excel and it is autodownloading the file but while showing the alert msg its not working
Response.ClearContent();      //Clear contents of current Response.
Response.BufferOutput = true; //Buffer output before sending.
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExportData.xlsx");
Response.BinaryWrite(fileContents);
Response.Flush(); //Send buffered output to client.
Response.End();

Both script manager and JavaScript code not working
string script = @"<script>
    Toastify({
       text: 'Excel file downloaded successfully!',
       duration: 3000,  // Display duration for the message (in milliseconds)
       className: 'info'  // Optional class name for the toast message
    }).showToast();
</script>";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "DownloadStatusScript", script, false);

Need to show the alert message after excel gets downloaded in an alert box or some dialog box. Project is in .net.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You cannot download a file AND update the UI at the same time.

I wrote an extension method for downloading excel from ExcellPackage in web api. See if that works for you.
public static HttpResponseMessage ToExcelHttpResponseMessage(this ExcelPackage package, string FileName)
{
    var bytes = package.GetAsByteArray();

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
    response.Content = response.Content;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = FileName;

    return response;
}

Usage:
return youExcelPackage.ToExcelHttpResponseMessage("ExcelFileName.xlsx");

